# Why state doesn't keep all the data in Array state in hook when it updated in foreach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, react-hooks, state

I want to update my Array state in hook by foreach but it just keeps the last one. I also used the empty array for useEffect to stop re-render each time by updating state.

```
import './App.css';
import Card from "./Card"
import Books from "./Books"
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios"
import BooksInfo from './Books';
function App() {
  const [bookInfo,setBookInfo] = useState([])
  useEffect( ()=>{
    let bname = ""
    let bauthor = ""
    let bcover = 0
    async function getInfo(){
        let results = Promise.all(BooksInfo.map(book=>{
          let result = axios.get(`https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=${book}`)
          return result
        }))
        ;(await results).forEach(result=>{
          console.log(result)
            bname= result.data.docs[0].title_suggest
            bauthor= result.data.docs[0].author_name[0]
            bcover= result.data.docs[0].cover_i
            setBookInfo([...bookInfo , { name:bname , author:bauthor  , cover:bcover }]);
            console.log(bookInfo)
        })
    }

    getInfo()
  },[])
```

Here is the additional code for the one of the comments: This code help me to understand how state and useEffect work.

```
function App(){
  console.log("App Rendered!");

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [test, setTest] = useState(0)
  const [run,setRun] = useState(0)
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("inside useEffect")
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
    setTest(test => test +counter)

  },[run])
  const count= ()=>{
    console.log("test")
    setRun(run => run + 2)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={count}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setBookInfo` function is async, so there is nothing guarantee that after a each iteration, the data of `bookInfo` is updated with new inserted data. The `map` function is more suitable for your situation

```js
const newBookInfor = (await results).map((result) => {
    let bname = "";
    let bauthor = "";
    let bcover = 0;
    bname = result.data.docs[0].title_suggest;
    bauthor = result.data.docs[0].author_name[0];
    bcover = result.data.docs[0].cover_i;
    return { name: bname, author: bauthor, cover: bcover };
});
setBookInfo(newBookInfor);
```

Comment: Main problem is not `setBookInfo` being asynchronous; problem is that state is constant within a particular render of a component. Component can't see the updated state _until_ it re-renders.

Comment: He used the spread operator on `setBookInfo`, it will create a new reference of `bookInfo` variable.

Comment: spread syntax will create a new array BUT the state will be same, it won't include the object added in the previous iteration of the `forEach()` method.

Comment: It sounds weird to me. Could you give me the reason why `the state will be the same`?

Comment: Because state cannot change within the same render of the component. If you change the state after the first render, component won't see the updated state _until_ it re-renders; it will see the updated state _after_ the second render. As OP is calling `setBookInfo` multiple times and _spreading_ the `bookInfo`, that `bookInfo` will be the same data (different object because of `spread syntax`) in each iteration of the `forEach` method.

Comment: @dothuan Thanks for your response. It works but why did you use await before results.map() because without await it still works ? could you please explain about await because I still confuse about await and async function.

Comment: @YasamanForouzesh I see you use `(await results)` so I just add it to my answer.

Comment: @dothuan So When we update the state in useEffect immediately the component will be re-render so it can see the new value of the state but states wouldn't be able to use their new value until end of the use effect that make another render. I updated my above code and I add the small code to help so try it. It will help you to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, setBookInfo is an async call, When you use it inside the loop it won't take the latest value for the next iteration. Instead, it takes the last value(initial). that's why it shows the last value.

```
import "./App.css";
import Card from "./Card";
import Books from "./Books";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import BooksInfo from "./Books";
function App() {
  const [bookInfo, setBookInfo] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getInfo() {
      let results = await Promise.all(
        BooksInfo.map((book) => {
          let result = axios.get(
            `https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=${book}`
          );
          return result;
        })
      );

      const finalResult = results.map((result) => {
        let bname = "";
        let bauthor = "";
        let bcover = 0;
        console.log(result);
        bname = result.data.docs[0].title_suggest;
        bauthor = result.data.docs[0].author_name[0];
        bcover = result.data.docs[0].cover_i;
        return { name: bname, author: bauthor, cover: bcover };
      });
      setBookInfo([...bookInfo, ...finalResult]);
    }
    getInfo();
  }, []);
}
```